# How can I lock a function on the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a sidebar which expands on hover.

Because expanding, collapsing can disturb sometimes I want to unbind the hovering when someone clicks on the sidebar.

The code at the bottom works for unbinding the first time but the second click to reenable the hovering again doesn't work:

```
    $('.action').click(function(){
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).bind('mouseenter').bind('mouseleave');
        });
    });
```

So how can I bind the hovering again when locked (please no if construction).

Regards

Comment: _please no if construction_ - why?

Comment: without using  *if* conditions, you have to attach and detach the event handler every time, which is really **bad**

Comment: I try to avoid much logic in jquery but there seems to be no other good way :)

Comment: @user1246987 you should be aware that adding and removing event listeners this way (=multiple times), and thus manipulating the DOM, is considered as an anti-pattern and a bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.action').on('mouseenter mouseleave', doStuffOnHover); //initial handler

var bound = true;

$('.action').on('click', function(){
      $(this)[bound ? 'off' : 'on']('mouseenter mouseleave', doStuffOnHover);
      bound=bound ? false:true;
});

function doStuffOnHover() {
   //do stuff here
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HwNTB/)

If doing different things on mouseenter/leave, you will of course need two functions.

Comment: `bound=bound ? false:true;`? wth - why not simply `bound = !bound;`?

Comment: Well, yeah sure, I just did the same thing as on the line above, consistency and all :-)...

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the actual event `.bind('mouseenter', function () { /* whatever */ });`.  jQuery doesn't automatically know you want to re-bind what was already there.  If you want, you can use a named function so you don't have to rewrite it.